# How can I delete the selected messages (with checkboxes) in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm making a messaging system and it has a lot of AJAX. I'm trying to add a bulk actions feature with check boxes. I've added the checkboxes, but my problem is that I don't know how to make something happen to the selected messages.

Here's my function that happens whenever a checkbox is clicked:

```
function checkIt(id) {
    if ($('#checkbox_' + id).is(':checked')) {
        $('#' + id).addClass("selected");
    }
    else {
        $('#' + id).removeClass("selected");
    }
}
```

But, I don't know where to go from there.

[image]

Here is some example markup for one of the lines [generated by PHP] of the list of messages:

```
<div class="line" id="33" >

<span class="inbox_check_holder">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_33" onclick="checkIt(33)" id="checkbox_33" class="inbox_check" />
<span class="star_clicker" id="star_33" onclick="addStar(33)" title="Not starred">
<img id="starimg_33" class="not_starred" src="images/blank.gif">
</span>
</span>
<div class="line_inner" style="display: inline-block;" onclick="readMessage(33, 'Test')">
<span class="inbox_from">Nathan</span> 
<span class="inbox_subject" id="subject_33">Test</span> 
<span class="inbox_time" id="time_33" title="">[Time sent]</span> 
</div>

</div>
```

As you can see, each line has the `id` attribute set to the actual message ID.

In my function above you can see how I check it. But, now what I need to do is when the "Delete" button is clicked, send an AJAX request to delete all of the selected messages.

Here is what I currently have for the delete button:

```
$('#delete').click(function() {
if($('.inbox_check').is(':checked')) {

}
else {
alertBox('No messages selected.'); //this is a custom function
}
});
```

I will also be making bulk *Mark as Read, Mark as Unread, Remove Star,* and *Add Star* buttons so once I know how to make this bulk Delete work, I can use that same method to do these other things.

And for the PHP part, how would I delete all them that get sent in the AJAX request with a `mysql_query`? I know it would have to have something to do with an array, but I just don't know the code to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. you need some way to relate each checkbox with an associated record in the database - maybe the record's primary key should be in the checkbox's `value` attribute. 2. use jquery's .ajax() call to invoke the server-side script, collecting all the checked checkboxes and sending their values to the server. 3. the serve collects those values and does whatever it has to with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this

```
$('#delete').click(function() {
    var checked = $('.inbox_check:checked');
    var ids = checked.map(function() {
        return this.value;  // why not store the message id in the value?
    }).get().join(",");
    if (ids) {
        $.post(deleteUrl, {idsToDelete:ids}, function() {
            checked.closest(".line").remove();
        });
    }
    else {
        alertBox('No messages selected.'); // this is a custom function
    }
});
```

**Edit:** Just as a side comment, you don't need to be generating those incremental ids.  You can eliminate a lot of that string parsing and leverage jQuery instead.  First, store the message id in the value of the checkbox.  Then, in any click handler for a given line:

```
var line = $(this).closest(".line");  // the current line
var isSelected = line.has(":checked");  // true if the checkbox is checked
var msgId = line.find(":checkbox").val();  // the message id
var starImg = line.find(".star_clicker img");  // the star image
```

Comment: Yeah, I can definitely store it in the value. Thanks so much! I will put this in right now and try it out :) But, I don't know what mysql_query keyword I would use to remove all of the IDs that are sent in the `$.post`. Any ideas? I know it would start as `DELETE FROM table WHERE to_user='$user'` but I don't know what else I'd do.

Comment: I'm not great with MySQL, but you probably want something like `DELETE FROM table WHERE to_user = '$user' AND message_id IN ('$messageIds')`.

Comment: @Nathan - The raw SQL should have `... AND message_id IN (123, 456, 789)` or `... AND message_id IN ('abc', 'def', 'ghi')` for numbers and strings respectively.  Being more of a C#/SQL Server guy, I'm not sure the exact PHP syntax to get that SQL Script.  Hopefully that's enough to get you there though.

Comment: Oh, I see. That MySQL helps. (I'm pretty sure that `DELETE FROM table WHERE to_user = '$user' AND message_id IN ('$messageIds')` is the correct PHP syntax) Thanks :)

Comment: This is only deleting one. It removes it on the page but it is really only deleting one of the selected out of the database. How can I fix this?

Comment: Nathan, I updated the code above to include debugging. Please report back what ids are shown as being deleted. If it is the same id again and again (I assume so), this is the problem.

Comment: @Nur Okay, I added this (instead of putting it in the JS console I went ahead and let it be an alert), here's the results - seems to be working: http://screencast.com/t/g0feYaat As you can see I added extra stuff to it (like the loader and confirm dialog) but that wouldn't do anything as it was having this same issue before I added those. So I think it's a not a problem with the JS but a problem with the PHP, am I correct? Also, come to think of it, looks like I'm using gilly3's code. This is the JavaScript I have right now: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25819920/my_js.txt Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @nathan - there must be an error in your SQL code.  Can you write out your generated SQL expression to the page so it can be debugged?

Comment: @gilly3 Yeah, sorry for such a delayed reply. I printed it and it just printed `1`. It works when I select one and delete, but when I select multiple messages none of them delete from the database. Would you like me to edit my question with my SQL in it?

Comment: My SQL is: `$result = mysql_query("UPDATE messages SET deleted='yes' WHERE to_user = '$user' AND type='conv' AND conv_id IN ('$messageIds')") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: I got it to work! It was an error with my MySQL query. It was supposed to be `IN ($ids)` instead of `IN ('$ids')`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming each checkbox has a parent div or td:

```
function removeDatabaseEntry(reference_id)
{
    var result = null;
    var scriptUrl = './databaseDelete.php';
    $.ajax({
        url: scriptUrl,
        type: 'post',
        async: false,
        data: {id: reference_id},
        success: function(response)
        {
            result = response;
        }
    )};
    return result;
}
$('.inbox_check').each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        var row = $(this).parent().parent();
        var id = row.attr('id');
        if (id == null)
        {
            alert('My selector needs updating');
            return false;
        }
        var debug = 'Deleting ' + id + ' now...';
        if (console) console.log(debug);
        else alert(debug);
        row.remove();
        var response = removeDatabaseEntry(id);

        // Tell the user something happened
        $('#response_div').html(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: This would be in your onsubmit or onclick function

Comment: This will only remove it on the page. Once I refresh, it'll be back. It wont remove it from the MySQL database table. (which is why I have to use an AJAX request. But I also don't know what `mysql_query` code to use)

Comment: I was hoping to give you "part" of a solution. Not the entire solution. I figured this would spur more conversation and we could estimate exactly what else was needed. I will update my code to include an ajax request. I will need to know the table names and field values/relationships before I can accurately tell you the SQL

Comment: Oh okay. (I wasn't the one that down voted it, by the way) My table name is `messages`, the column name for the ID of the ticket is `id` (obviously) Do you need any other field/column names?

Comment: Thanks! :) Now I need to figure out which answer I should "accept"... ;)